# hibernate not creating table but no error messages

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, spring-boot

I am doing a spring-boot project and trying to create a table with hibernate, I get no errors when I run the app and the server starts normally, but the table does not get created.

StatusUpdate.java

```
package model;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.persistence.PrePersist;

@Entity
@Table(name="status_update")
public class StatusUpdate {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="text")
    private String text;

    @Column(name="added")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date added;

    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate() {
        if (added == null) {
            added = new Date();
        }
    }

    public StatusUpdate(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public StatusUpdate(String text, Date added) {
        this.text = text;
        this.added = added;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public Date getAdded() {
        return added;
    }

    public void setAdded(Date added) {
        this.added = added;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((added == null) ? 0 : added.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((text == null) ? 0 : text.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        StatusUpdate other = (StatusUpdate) obj;
        if (added == null) {
            if (other.added != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!added.equals(other.added))
            return false;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        if (text == null) {
            if (other.text != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!text.equals(other.text))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <tiles.version>3.0.7</tiles.version>
    </properties>

    <groupId>com.voja</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-tutorial</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
            <version>${tiles.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>${tiles.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.38</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties

```
debug=true

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springboottutorial
spring.datasource.username=springboot
spring.datasource.password=hello
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
```

I also get a yellow line under `dialect` in this line `spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect`which says `spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect' is an unknown property. Did you mean 'spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto' in case that might be a problem.

Comment: whats does your persistence.xml look like?

Comment: As @911DidBush mentioned please show your persistence.xml. The parameter hbm2ddl.auto is important here.

Comment: you can add `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` to your `application.properties` to see more logs. Maybe you can find something

Comment: @911DidBush I am new to java and spring. Where is that file? I did not create one if I was supposed to, I am following a tutorial and that wasn't done.

Comment: I also added my application,properties file to the Q.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem by reading another post, actually there was a problem with packages and classes within them, they couldn't find one another and so the table wasn't created.

I made a new project and put all classes inside the same package and it worked, so I will fix my existing project based on that.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes the problem occurs in the property name you choose. Like text,  value etc. which are reserved keyword for database. Hence you can see a log of creating table but table will not be created. To resolve this just change you property name in you bean or provide explicit column name.

Example: property or column name "value" is not supported in mysql. Hence my tables were not created. I have to rename it to 'valueString'.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I guess this was supposed to be a comment and you didnt have enough reputation?

Answer (score 1):

For your **application.properties** file follow below link for this

it is like :
`spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true`
and then add
`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop`

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties

Comment: `spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true` and then add `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop`

Answer (score 1):

It's not working for you, because you are not using it, I mean, JPA creates the database when needs to use it. You can try to write a test that uses it, or add a rest repository to try it, just add this to your application.properties;

```
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

and then create this interface:

```
    @RepositoryRestResource
    public interface IStatusRepository extends CrudRepository<StatusUpdate,   Long> {
  }
```

You will need also this dependency;

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

It's more easy just creating a test, but I guess you are trying to build a rest web service, so try this to see it works =)

Comment: I am not trying to create a rest web service, just a basic website (following  a tutorial). Is there something I could add to `StausUpdate.jjava` in order to make it work?

Comment: I created your same project, with this application.properties and it just work fine, table is created without any problem with your same code:
 
             `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/suscripciones?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.name = dataSource
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
   `

Comment: is it in eclipse? If so, could you zip the whole project and upload it somewhere so I can compare?

Answer (score -1):

If you are using jpa and hibernate then add the following property in your **application.properties** file

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Comment: change the dialect to this : **org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect**

Comment: try adding all the properties listed in this [link](http://christoph-burmeister.eu/?p=2849)

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this to your application.properties :

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```