# Spring-data-jpa + Hibernate does not creating an expected table but creates other fine

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

My Spring Boot Application was creating all the tables without a problem for months, but now it does not create one table, the others are created without problems in the same app.

I tried using this solution.... [hibernate not creating table but no error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39410576/hibernate-not-creating-table-but-no-error-messages)

But it does not work.

I gives me no errors...

This is my application.properties:

> site.url=http://localhost:8080

```
debug=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springboottutorial
spring.datasource.username=springboot
spring.datasource.password=hello
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect

spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
```

I'm not sure if it makes sense to put the class since it has not changed since it was working fine... anyway

```
    package com.caveofprogramming.model.entity;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.PrePersist;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

@Entity
@Table(name="statusupdate")
public class StatusUpdate {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Size(min=5, max=255, message="{addstatus.title.size}")
    @Column(name="title")
    private String title;

    @Size(min=5, max=25000, message="{addstatus.text.size}")
    @Column(name="text")
    private String text;

    @Column(name = "added")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss")
    private Date added;

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = SiteUser.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private SiteUser siteUser;

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = Photo.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idphotostatus")
    private Photo photo;

    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate() {
        if (added == null) {
            added = new Date();
        }
    }

    public StatusUpdate() {
    }

    public StatusUpdate(String title, String text) {
        this.title = title;
        this.text = text;
    }

    public StatusUpdate(String title, String text, Date added, SiteUser siteUser) {
        this.title = title;
        this.text = text;
        this.added = added;
        this.siteUser = siteUser;
    }

    public StatusUpdate(Long id, String title, String text, Date added, SiteUser siteUser, Photo photo) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.text = text;
        this.added = added;
        this.siteUser = siteUser;
        this.photo = photo;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public Date getAdded() {
        return added;
    }

    public void setAdded(Date added) {
        this.added = added;
    }

    public SiteUser getSiteUser() {
        return siteUser;
    }

    public void setSiteUser(SiteUser siteUser) {
        this.siteUser = siteUser;
    }

    public Photo getPhoto() {
        return photo;
    }

    public void setPhoto(Photo photo) {
        this.photo = photo;
    }

@Override
    public String toString() {
        return "StatusUpdate [id=" + id + ", title=" + title + ", text=" + text + ", added=" + added + ", siteUser="
                + siteUser + ", photo=" + photo + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: can you list the entity for which table is not getting created?

Comment: yes add the mapping class also

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by the mapping class... the controller? the dao? the service?

Comment: Do all the tables having the same package?
Can you check whether the component scan configured properly to scan the "com.caveofprogramming.model.entity"

Comment: Yes, all the @Entity classes are in the same package: com.caveofprogramming.model.entity . What do you mean by component scan?

Comment: something like this.. @ComponentScan("com.caveofprogramming")
so it can scan the @Entity if annotation allowed

Comment: No, no @ComponentScan. Where should it be?