# Hibernate auto-update does not create table for specific entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a Java Spring MVC app using Hibernate and a MySQL 5.7 DB. Hibernate is configured to automatically update the schema from new entities via: `<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>`

It is working for all the entities in my app except for one:

```java
@Entity
@IdClass(QuestionId.class)
@Getter
@Setter
@Accessors(chain = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Question {
    @Id
    private String key;

    @Id
    private Long version;

    @Type(type = "json")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "json")
    private JsonNode metaData;
}
```

This entity is defined in exactly the same way as other entities, but when the app starts, this particular table does not get created in the DB. There are no error messages given that I have been able to uncover.

Answer (score 0):

I actually discovered the problem with help from an answer to a different question: [hibernate not creating table but no error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39410576/hibernate-not-creating-table-but-no-error-messages)

This behavior can happen when using **reserved db keywords as property/column names**. In my case, `key` is a reserved keyword in MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html

```java
public class Question {
    @Id
    private String key; // <==== NO; `KEY` is a db reserved keyword.

    @Id
    private Long version;

    @Type(type = "json")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "json")
    private JsonNode metaData;
}
```

Changing the property name (or alternatively specifying an explicit column name) fixes the issue. There may have been an error message if I enabled the right debugging flags, but the problem was solved before then.